# How to improve this Agda function with standard libraries?

Tags: agda

The `deq` function below returns a `Dec` instance for `Name`, which either holds a String, or prefixes a `Name` with one of two constructors.

```
data Name : Set where
  Str : String -> Name
  Cp0 : Name -> Name
  Cp1 : Name -> Name

deq : (a : Name) -> (b : Name) -> Dec (a ≡ b)
deq (Str a) (Str b) with iseq a b
deq (Str a) (Str b) | yes p = yes (cong Str p)
deq (Str a) (Str b) | no ¬p = no f
  where f : (Str a ≡ Str b) -> ⊥
        f refl = ¬p refl
deq (Str a) (Cp0 b) = no (λ ())
deq (Str a) (Cp1 b) = no (λ ())
deq (Cp0 a) (Str b) = no (λ ())
deq (Cp0 a) (Cp0 b) with deq a b
deq (Cp0 a) (Cp0 b) | yes p = yes (cong Cp0 p)
deq (Cp0 a) (Cp0 b) | no ¬p = no f
  where f : (Cp0 a ≡ Cp0 b) -> ⊥
        f refl = ¬p refl
deq (Cp0 a) (Cp1 b) = no (λ ())
deq (Cp1 a) (Str b) = no (λ ())
deq (Cp1 a) (Cp0 b) = no (λ ())
deq (Cp1 a) (Cp1 b) with deq a b
deq (Cp1 a) (Cp1 b) | yes p = yes (cong Cp1 p)
deq (Cp1 a) (Cp1 b) | no ¬p = no f
  where f : (Cp1 a ≡ Cp1 b) -> ⊥
        f refl = ¬p refl
```

But here, a few clauses are awkward because they need a `where`. Is the standard-library had a `cong` equivalent that allowed us to turn `a ≡ b -> ⊥` into `F a ≡ F b -> ⊥` for a constructor `F`, then we could make this definition shorter. Also, if we could do the pattern matching inline with lambdas, we could improve it too, but for that we'd need to annotate the lambda input with a type. Is there any way to improve this definition?

Comment: This question pops up [from time to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297779/equality-testing-without-explicit-proof-that-data-constructors-are-injective). In short, I've never seen an improvement. You can improve other things, though, like use decidable equality combinators in order to simplify the definition of `deq`. I have plenty [here](https://github.com/effectfully/Generic/blob/0684b28da4614aa483d6f12b9a414acdce2d2807/src/Generic/Lib/Decidable.agda) (`decSum` and `decProd` are examples of how they can be used).

Comment: Or you can simplify your life and use either [Ulf's prelude](https://github.com/UlfNorell/agda-prelude) which allows to derive decidable equality using the reflection machinery or use [my library](https://github.com/effectfully/Generic) which allows the same, but is 1) less capable than Ulf's 2) compatible with the standard library. Generating an `Eq` instance for your `Name` is `open import Generic.Main hiding (Name; NameEq); instance NameEq : Eq Name; unquoteDef NameEq = deriveEqTo NameEq (quote Name)`.

Comment: You can get rid of the `where`s by writing `no λ {refl → ¬p refl}`.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, indeed. I wonder whether it has always worked like that or pattern matching lambdas were improved at some point.

Comment: Oh, so the reason my attempt didn't work is that `(λ refl → ¬p refl)` isn't actually a pattern match, you need the `{}`. Damn.